# Require js loading time issue

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have developing the backbone js application. I have used the require js to load the other js from server. Everything is working fine but the require js start loading the other js file about 8-9SEC later. 
If you have any solution then please share.

**Below is the code sample which I have used in main.js**

```
var req = require.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    catchError: true,
    paths: {
        'app': 'app',
    'routes': 'routes',
    'core': 'core',
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone',
    'handlebars': 'libs/handlebars',
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'libs/jquery-ui',
        'json2': 'libs/json2',
        'underscore': 'libs/underscore',
    'slimscroll': 'libs/prettify/slimscroll'
    },
    shim: {
        'app': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'handlebars'],
            exports: 'azx'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'core': {
            deps: ['app'],
            exports: 'Core'
        },
        'handlebars': {
            deps: [],
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        },
        'underscore': {
            deps: [],
            exports: '_'
        },
    }    
});
```

Comment: did you consider using r.js?

Comment: There's nothing in this question which suggests that the currently accepted answer is the solution. So the question does not contain all the information necessary to diagnose the problem. A general node on SO: the questions and answers posted to SO must be of value to the general community (that is, be of value to *others*) to merit being kept on SO.

Comment: I don't know much. But when I have gone with answer my require js start loading content most frequently as compare to the previous time.  I am new for backbone application development. If you have any solution then please provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this . You can use DOM manipulation to create a new script tag at runtime. So you can add first of your script tag.

```
setTimeout( function() {

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "require.js"; // give full path
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

} , 10);
```